# Not able to get contents of JSON / Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

new to php.... can't seem to get the contents of this array... ie. trying to do: `$key = var0  and  $value = string0`

This is what I am trying the following, with no success:

```
$getJSON = [
    {
        "item0": [
            {"var0":"string0"},
            {"var1":"string1"},
            {"var2":"string2"},
            {"var3":"string3"}
        ]
    }
]

$arr = json_decode( $getJSON, true );

$test1 = $arr[0]['item0']['var0'];
$test2 = $arr['item0']['var0'];
```

Comment: Can you show what $arr is ? use var_dump($arr);

Comment: Are you really assigning to `$getJSON` after you call `json_decode($getJSON, true)`?

Comment: @Barmar no its being assigned before calling. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Is that code even running? It's invalid PHP syntax.

Comment: You are missin " after string3

Comment: I've updated my resdponse fixing the json part.

Comment: @barmar I ended up changing the array structure from having separate objects to as you both had suggested. Thank you for the input and the help, definitely learned something new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all fix your json part:

```
$json = '{
    "item0": [
        {"var0": "string0"},
        {"var1": "string1"},
        {"var2": "string2"},
        {"var3": "string3"}
    ]
}';
```

Now if you var_dump the json_decoded content with

```
json_decode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

you will obtain

```
array(1) {


'item0' =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    array(1) {
      'var0' =>
      string(7) "string0"
    }
    [1] =>
    array(1) {
      'var1' =>
      string(7) "string1"
    }
    [2] =>
    array(1) {
      'var2' =>
      string(7) "string2"
    }
    [3] =>
    array(1) {
      'var3' =>
      string(7) "string3"
    }
  }
}
```

This means that you can get values with:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($decoded['item0'][0]['var0']);
```

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: @sensorario this worked perfectly. but ended up changing the array data structure as you had mentioned first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `json_decode()` has to be a string, not an array. So put it in quotes.

```
$getJSON = '[
    {
        "item0": [
            {"var0":"string0"},
            {"var1":"string1"},
            {"var2":"string2"},
            {"var3":"string3"}
        ]
    }
]';
```

After you decode, `$arr[0]['item0']` contains an array, so to get the `var0` element it would be `$arr[0]['item0'][0]['var0']`.

Having an array of separate objects, each with different keys, is probably not a great design. It would be better if the you did it like this:

```
$getJSON = '{
    "item0": {
        "var0":"string0",
        "var1":"string1",
        "var2":"string2",
        "var3":"string3"
    }
}'
```

Then the value you want would be:

```
$arr['item0']['var0']
```

Comment: Is not a valid json

Comment: @sensorario The JSON in the question had a typo, a missing quote after `string3`, and I copied that without noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
First change Desing of json pattern

$getJSON = '{"item0":[
                        {"var0":"string0"},
                        {"var1":"string1"},
                        {"var2":"string2"},
                        {"var3":"string3"}
                     ]
            }';

use json_decode function for get json data

$arr = json_decode( $getJSON);

echo $arr->item0[0]->var0.'</br>';
echo $arr->item0[1]->var1.'</br>';
echo $arr->item0[2]->var2.'</br>';
echo $arr->item0[3]->var3.'</br>';
```